# Redux toolkit state property that is dependent on other state property

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

With redux toolkit what is the correct way of defining one state property that is dependent on other state property? I need something like:

```
const initialState: AppSliceState = {
  words: "",
  cursor: 0,
 ** typedChars: words.substring(0, cursor),
  remainingChars: words.substring(cursor, words.length - 1),**
};
```

In my app I fetch some text from api and put it in words property. Then when user starts typing, cursor property is increased on every typed key. For example if fetched words is "Hello!" and user press H then cursor becomes 1 and typedChars should be "H", and remainingChars should be "ello!"

I think I can define typedChars in my App component but in that case I may have props drilling which I would like to avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a use case for `createSelector`, as you are deriving data:

https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors

```
const selectWords = state => state.words
const selectCursor = state => state.cursor

const selectTypedChars = createSelector([selectWords, selectCursor], (words, cursor) => {
    return words.substring(0, cursor)
})

const selectRemainingChars = createSelector([selectWords, selectCursor], (words, cursor) => {
    return words.substring(cursor, words.length - 1)
})
```

and then where you need it you can just do

```
const typedChars = useSelector(selectTypedChars)
```